How to decrypt already encrypted string using public pem file key in python
I have an encrypted license.lic file, which is encrypted using private pem file in php. Below is the code:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
and now there is C# code by using encrypted code is getting decrypted using public pem file:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Now I want to do the same decryption functionality in python. In simple words whatever C# code is doing I want to do the same in python. I only want to decrypt the license.lic file using python.
I have tried to that and took many samples from chatgpt, but got no luck. I get this error:
'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust.openssl.rsa.RSAPublicKey' object has no attribute 'decrypt' python public key
At the end chatgpt says:
Using private key we encrypts the data and using same private key we decrypt the data but in our case C# is using public pem file to decrypt the data so why python can not use the same public pem file to decrypt the data?
Anyone please help me out, and thanks for looking at it.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/DavzpIr4.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/QL7UGznZ.png
Below is the python code for decryption with public pem file in which I am getting this error message:
Decryption error: 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust.openssl.rsa.RSAPublicKey' object has no attribute 'decrypt'
def decrypt_license(file_path, pub_key):
try:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as lic_file:
        lic_data = lic_file.read()

    # Extract the base64 encoded license data between the LICENSE delimiters
    base64_data = re.search(r"-----BEGIN LICENSE-----(.*?)-----END LICENSE-----", lic_data, re.DOTALL).group(1).strip()
    cipher_text = base64.b64decode(base64_data)

    # Decrypt the license data using the public key
    decrypted_data = pub_key.decrypt(
        cipher_text,
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )
    return decrypted_data.decode('utf-8')
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Decryption error: {e}")
    return None


Sounds like ChatGPT has gone and hallucinated some part of the cryptography API, which it is rather prone to doing. I’d recommend trying to find some existing code samples online or just reading the documentation yourself.
